# Simple problem with testing contracts with Truffle

Tags: javascript, ethereum, truffle

I have got a Marketplace.test.js file that gives syntax error even before the `const` in the test file when I put "truffle test" in the terminal.

I've googled and looked for answers but to no avail.  I feel like this should be easy to solve but no results yet.  Still a noob when it comes to working with blockchain and it's quite frustrating.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
const Marketplace = artifacts.require('./Marketplace.sol')

contract('Marketplace', (accounts) => {
    let marketplace

    before(async () => {
        marketplace = await Marketplace.deployed()
    })

    describe('deployment', async () => {
        it('deploys successfully', async () => {
            const address = await marketplace.address
            assert.notEqual(address, 0x0)
            assert.notEqual(address, '')
            assert.notEqual(address, null)
            assert.notEqual(address, undefined)
        })
    })
})
```

> SyntaxError: C:/ETHDev/marketplace/test/Marketplace.test.js:
>   Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
>
> > 1 | ��c o n s t   M a r k e t p l a c e   =   a r t i f a c t s . r e q u i r e ( ' . / M a r k e t p l a c e . s o l ' ) ;

Comment: That looks like a file encoding issue. Make sure to use a plain text editor, with standard UTF-8 encoding. In good editors you may also activate a feature to be able to see any blank character, you might want to check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be because of the editor you are using, Try switching to any other editors.

If in the case you are using notepad++ change this setting. `"Encoding" -> "Convert to UTF-8 without BOM"`